# PHP to set Wordpress post featured image as background

Tags: php, wordpress

I need the featured image on all pages and posts to be displayed as the background of a div, `.banner_image`. I found some PHP online that managed to get it working on pages, but on posts nothing happens. Can anyone let me know how I could amend the following code to also pull images from WP Posts?

```
function cs_single_bg() {
if(is_page())
{
    $cs_page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $cs_post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $cs_page_id );
    $cs_bkgdImg = wp_get_attachment_url( $cs_post_thumbnail_id );        
    ?>
        <style>
            .banner_image { 
                background-image: url(<? echo $cs_bkgdImg ?>);
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                }
        </style>
     <?    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always do development after WP_DEBUG flag on,

```
function cs_single_bg() {
if(is_singular()) // Check a page in case post is_post()
{
    $cs_page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $cs_post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $cs_page_id );
    $cs_bkgdImg = wp_get_attachment_url( $cs_post_thumbnail_id );        
    ?>
        <style>
            .banner_image { 
                background-image: url(<?php echo $cs_bkgdImg ?>);
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                }
        </style>
     <?    }
}
```

Here you are missing

```
        background-image: url(<?php echo $cs_bkgdImg ?>);
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't make a difference; it was already working on Pages; I need it to include some code to pull the featured image for if you're viewing a post...

Comment: can you put screenshot??

Comment: Solved! All I had to do was change the second line to if(is_singular()) {